# Are laws about sex outside marriage less rigorously enforced in Dubai for people on layovers?

Tags: legal, layovers, dubai, uae, sex

Last night, I saw on the news that Qantas was switching its main hub from Singapore to Dubai. (Qantas has since [switched back](http://www.traveller.com.au/qantas-moves-a380-london-stopover-from-dubai-to-singapore-the-city-with-the-worlds-best-airport-hub-gy85dl?promote_channel=edmail&mbnr=MzgxNjcxNQ&eid=email:nnn-13omn645-ret_newsl-membereng:nnn-04%2F11%2F2013-smh_travel-dom-travel-nnn-smh-u&campaign_code=13ITR004&name=10078_traveller_news&instance=2017-09-01--01-59--UTC) to Singapore)

Smart Traveller [notes](http://www.smartraveller.gov.au/zw-cgi/view/Advice/United_Arab_Emirates) about the United Arab Emirates:

> Homosexual acts and sex outside of marriage: Homosexual acts and all
>   kinds of sex outside of marriage are illegal and may lead to severe
>   punishment, including imprisonment and fines. Foreigners have been
>   imprisoned for having sex with people to whom they are not legally
>   married. De facto relationships and civil unions are not recognised in
>   the UAE and any sexual acts within these relationships are considered
>   to be sex outside of marriage. It is also against the law in the UAE
>   to live together or share the same hotel room with someone of the
>   opposite sex to whom you are not married or closely related. If
>   checking into a hotel as a couple, you may be asked by management to
>   prove that you are legally married. These laws apply equally to UAE
>   residents as well as visitors.

Should I assume that when Smart Traveller says that the laws apply equally to visitors, that includes even people who are just on layovers? Or are the laws less rigorously enforced for people on layovers?

**Background:** I'm not planning on engaging in homosexuality, adultery or fornication in Dubai, but I'd rather not financially support airline routes that would expose fellow passengers to the risk of jail.

Comment: An example of someone else being concerned over the hub being Dubai: http://www.smh.com.au/travel/travel-news/emiratesqantas-deal-warning-over-tough-justice-in-stopover-city-20120920-26834.html

Comment: I'm confused about your last statement - "I'd rather not financially support airline routes that would expose fellow passengers to the risk of jail" - they're not.  If you choose to visit a country, you must choose to follow their laws while you're there.  I'm not saying I agree with their laws, but they're *their* laws, so if we want to visit their country, we should respect their right to make their own rules.

Comment: Well, Mark, that only goes so far. Unjust rules are still unjust. To compare, 'we' should not respect the Taliban's right to keep girls out of school, or Israel's right to keep Palestinians from their own land. The only thing 'we' have to accept is that we will be treated according to their laws when entering their country, as you first say.

Comment: @MarkMayo If someone's going to Europe from Australia, are they choosing to visit Dubai?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm If one has a choice of hub location based on airline, the airline choice also entails a hub choice. As QANTAS have actively chosen Dubai in place of Singapore they too have actively chosen to accept the conditions imposed by that country. FWIW Singapore also have had end enforced some relatively draconian laws in the past. eg men with long (by their definition) hair at one stage received compulsory haircuts. [In several visits to Singapore in recent years I did not notice any enforced restrictions on "normal" behaviour.]

Comment: You say "layover". I do not know if you mean that the travellers have cleared customs. If they have not then they are in international limbo and local laws probably do not apply as completely. ie production and operation of an automatic weapon may result in authorities igmoring fine distinctions of legal boundaries. Other actions may attract less attention.

Comment: @MastaBaba yeah, like I said, we should respect their *right* to make their rules, but we don't have to like the ones they make.  However, we must accept that if we choose to visit their country, we should abide by their rules, no matter how draconian / wrong they may seem to us.

Comment: No one is forcing you to come to Dubai, if you do not like the rules don't go.. The rules are wrong from your point of view, same thing goes for us, we think your rules are unfair... So grow up and learn how to accept others or simply don't go to others.

Comment: @MastaBaba and there you come into the definition of "just". At least one of the points you mention is extremely debatable, what you call "Palestinian land" isn't for very many people, including me and every Jew on the planet for example.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon local laws apply at airports even past customs.

Comment: People, please take it to chat!

Comment: I don't get all this fuss... Obviously, "airline routes that would expose fellow passengers to the risk of jail" was not to be taken literally, because the risk of jail exists in any country. Refusing to use a particular airline or route seems to me just as good a way to protest something as any other. (Personally, I refuse to use any of the Gulf carriers, despite their relatively attractive prices, for similar reasons.)

Comment: You could have left the last paragraph completely off the question, as well as rephrased the question itself in order to open it to all travelers, keeping the politics (and resultant political posturing) out of the comments and answers. _Why_ you want to travel (_or more importantly_ not want to travel) to any destination is off-topic by the rules of this SE. We _are not allowed to ask_ why you wish to avoid traveling, just give you advice about your asked question.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I never replied. Yes, they are. You could fly for less money via Bangkok, Hong Kong, Singapore, China, or even the US, and those are just the routes that I've taken.

Comment: @MarkMayo keep in mind not everyone is as expert in choosing routes as you are.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm not really expert to fly by the other ones - most major airlines go those routes.  Even Qantas is now changing from Dubai to Singapore as a hub.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Laws apply when you touch the ground of a country. The only way to get around that would be to go into a foreign embassy. There is no difference how long you are there or where you stay.

On top of that, places that have a very high traffic of foreigners will alert you if possible if you are trying to do something illegal. So if there are two guys in the UAE checking into the same hotel room, you can be sure to get a comment that this is not allowed. That does not mean that they cannot give you two rooms right next to each other - be it even with a convenient connecting door.

Regarding "exposing travelers": countries where strict laws apply such as Singapore and the middle East, I have had the experience that often you are very openly advised on the reasons you could get shot or life in prison for (drugs etc) already during the flight.

What I usually experienced is that when it comes to sex & alcohol, most countries that are rather strict on it, will offer the one or other way to get around the regulation - as long as you are discreet, and even more so if you are a foreigner. Provided you do not leave a cookie crumb trail that officials can follow, such as two guys checking into the same hotel room.

Comment: same hotel room will usually be fine, they just give you a room with 2 single beds. Had it happen more than once on organised trips, or traveling with my father (and no, I'm not homosexual, but the hotel crew would not know that as they never ask).

Answer (score 3):

If you're on a layover and not entering the country, that is, not going through immigration, you can expect that the law will not be equally enforced.

As soon as you go through immigration, expect it does, though even in practice you will find that this particular law, in the UAE, is not too strictly enforced, either for visitors or residents.
But, it *can* be. If you're going to stay a few nights in a hotel and have loud sex with your girlfriend, you could just find yourself deported. (Note, that I don't have hard proof for this, but all cases I remember of foreigners being charged, in any way, in the UAE, for unlawful sexual behaviour somehow really didn't try to be subtle.)

Comment: Not sure that's correct - in many cases the laws will apply to you while on an airside transit too

Comment: I am not sure I have seen a lot of hotels INSIDE the transit zone so you can stay there without going through immigration. And if there is, I would be highly surprised if that country's laws do not apply there.

Comment: You guys are right: the laws do apply, but are less likely to be as strictly enforced when in transit. Though I would not advise having sex in, say, the transit bathrooms, either with your wife or boyfriend.

Comment: Dubai airport does have [hotels inside the transit area](http://www.dubaiairport.com/en/passengers/AirportServices/Pages/DubaiInternationalHotel.aspx), so you could trigger the problems without even clearing immigration!

Comment: That could almost be a kafkaesque setup! :)